# If $H$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, show that the circles on $AH$ and $BC$ cut orthogonally.

Tags: geometry, circles

> If $H$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, show that the circles on $AH$ and $BC$ cut orthogonally.

If two circles cut orthogonally, it means that the angle between the tangents at the point of contact is 90 degrees.

[image: Diagram]

I've noticed that the points of intersection of circles are the feet of altitudes from $B$ and $C$.

I think this looks like. But I'm not able to proceed. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Does "the circle on $AH$" mean the circle whose diameter is $AH$?

Comment: @mathlove Yes. $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Let $D,E,F$ be a point on $BC,CA,AB$ such that $AD\perp BC,BE\perp AC,CF\perp AB$ respectively.

Then, we know that $E,F$ exist on the two circles.

Now consider the tangent lines at $F$ for both circles.

Then, let $G$ be a point both on the tangent line for the circle on $AH$ and on $BC$. Also, let $I$ be a point both on the tangent line for the circle on $BC$ and on $AC$.

Now we have
$$\angle{CFG}=\angle{FAH},\quad \angle{IFC}=\angle{FBC}$$

Since 
$$\angle{FAH}+\angle{FBC}=\angle{BAD}+\angle{ABD}=90^\circ$$
we have
$$\angle{CFG}+\angle{IFC}=90^\circ.$$

Comment: Why is $\angle CFG = \angle FAH$?

Comment: @Dhruv: Because of the alternate segment theorem, which states that the angle between the tangent and chord equals the angle in the alternate segment. see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMJIbtiBlKc). I'll add a figure.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $AB\perp CI$, $D$ on $CI$, draw circles as shown.  $AC$ meets the circles in $G$ and $H$, resp.  Now $GB\parallel HD$ (Thales), hence $\triangle ABG$ is similar to $\triangle DCH$.  Let the normals $FH$ and $EG$ meet in $J$.  Consider $EIFJ$.  Due to similarity the angles at $F$ and $E$ add up to $180^\circ$, so the angle at $J$ is $90^\circ$.

So regardless where you choose $D$, the normals and hence the tangents are perpendicular. Now if you choose $D$ to be the orthocenter, $G=H$ and the assertion follows.